# can you list some useful custom pipe in angular not in default pipe?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

Can you give some list of useful custom pipe, it's not in default pipe.It may be useful for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove Spaces:**

*Designing the pipe:*

```
import {Pipe} from "angular2/core";

@Pipe({
    name : "removeSpaces"
})

export class RemoveSpaces{
    transform(value){
        return value.replace(/ /g, "");
    }
}
```

*Using the pipe:*

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {RemoveSpaces} from './remove-spaces.ts';


@Component({
  selector: 'remove-spaces-impl',

})
@View({
    pipes: [RemoveSpaces],
    template: `
        <h2>Custom pipe : removeSpaces</h2>
        <h4> {{sampleString}} => {{sampleString | removeSpaces}}</h4>
        `
})
export class RemoveSpacesImpl {
    sampleString = "I love angular 2";
}
```